# Pausing iOS app game when User clicks Home Button

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, home-button

While the user is playing the game if they tap the Home Button on iPhone/iPad the game pauses itself but doesn't stay paused if the user clicks back on the app to open it, instead game leads them to game over screen. How do I code it that once the user clicks Home Button the game pauses and if they click back on app, within 2 seconds the game unpauses and you continue. Is there a particular code that goes inside the following methods that pauses the entire game and then unpauses it after a someone clicks on it and a few seconds go by?

```
  UIApplicationDelegatedelegate 
  -(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{}
  -(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{}
```

I got the app to pause in the background and stay paused but how do I make it that when the user EnterForeground again, there's about a 2 second delay before the game un-pauses?

Comment: Roughly speaking your engine is not aware that it is paused, and thinks time has gone on while suspended. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: If this is what you meant by your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487732/stop-game-app-if-home-button-clicked-ios then edit that question. Do not abandon the question and ask another that is almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS can't magically pause or un-pause your game for you - it's something you have to handle on your own in the code.

Once you have the logic to un-pause the game you can get the 2 seconds delay you mentioned in your question by calling `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` (see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:)). For example:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(continueGame) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0]
```

where `self` has a method called `continueGame` to .. continue the game. :)

Comment: I actually currently use the above code as my code for there being a delay before the GameOver screen appears but I completely forgot. Thanks for reminding me and that works.